# Why is the loop repeating the same value?

Tags: for-loop

In the code below, the intention is to get a new calculated value in cell J3 in each worksheet. But instead the value calculated in the first worksheet is repeated in cell J3 in all of the worksheets.  Can anyone offer a fix?  Thank you!

Sub Increment()

Dim i As Variant           '"i" for price increment
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim w As Integer           '"w" for each WorkSheet in the Workbook

'"WS_Count" is the number of Worksheets in the active Workbook
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For w = 1 To WS_Count

```
i = 0
    
Do Until i > Range("G3").Value

    i = i + 0.0025
    
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w).Range("J3").Value = i
```

Next w

End Sub